# The score is not deducted when other button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application, if the user correctly guessed the answer, 10 points will be given and then add to `newCoin` and then the `newCoin` value will be passed to next `Activity` using `Intent`.

Each question contains 3 helps.
When the user click help1, the score must be deducted by 10. If the user clicks `help2`, again the score must be deducted by 10 (the same goes with the help3)

When I click any help (help1/help2/help3) the `newCoin` is deducted by 10. But when I click another help the current coin is not deducted. What seems to be the problem?

here's my code

```
int scoreText;
int newScore, newCoin=0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.luzon2);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    int myValue=intent.getIntExtra("parameter name2", 0);
    final int newCoin=myValue;
    scoreTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    scoreTxt.setText("" + newCoin);

    luz2he1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz1);
    luz2he1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (newCoin>=10){
            newScore=(newCoin-10);
            scoreTxt.setText("" + newScore); 
        } 
    } });

    luz2he2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz2);
    luz2he2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (newCoin>=10){
            newScore=(newCoin-10);
            scoreTxt.setText("" + newScore); 
        } 
    } });

   luz2he3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLuz3);
   luz2he3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (newCoin>=10){
           newScore=(newCoin-10);
           scoreTxt.setText("" + newScore); 
       } 
   } });}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a couple minutes to fix that formatting so your code is easier to read? While you're at it, remove the code snippet. It only needs to be in code blocks

Comment: oops. sorry. okay i'll update.

Comment: In the event of the `luz2he2` button, you're not subtracting 10 coins

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `newCoin` is greater than 10 when you use another help? Set a log or breakpoint?

Comment: You seem to be  initializing newcoin always to 0 and later you are checking the coin if it's superior to 10 , so if the newcoin variable is below 10 this may not work , try using breakpoint or debug it locally before asking

Comment: yes i do. from the first activity the default coin is 50, when answered correctly +10. so the coin in the second activity is 60.

Comment: You should check that you are passing the proper value through your `Intent`. Do you mean for the space in `"parameter name2"`?

Comment: i am passing the coin across activities. the only problem is in the help buttons.

Comment: Ok, well you need to set a breakpoint or log and see what `newCoin` value is inside the `onClick()`s

Comment: @codeMagic how am i going to set a breakpoint? sorry, i dont know how.

Comment: Google search "How to set a breakpoint in <my IDE>"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the comments suggest that the OP is not familiar enough with programming to actually work on a problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 'newCoin' value in all help methods.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
             if (newCoin>=10){
                 newCoin -= 10;        
                 newScore = newCoin;
```

Comment: i have an error: The final local variable newCoin cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: You are just rewriting the same code

Comment: Is newCoin a final variable?

Comment: yes i declared new coin as final. final int newCoin=myValue;

Comment: when i remove the "final" i am having an error : Cannot refer to a non-final variable newCoin inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: then remove  final :)

Comment: declare newCoin as a global variable -> public class YourActivity extends Activity{

       int newCoin;